# javascript equivalent of preg_replace for following condition

Tags: javascript, preg-replace

I'm unable to find the alternative in JavaScript for following code :

```
$scene7_front_url = 
    preg_replace('/&wid=([0-9]+)*/', '&wid=100', $scene7_front_url) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have variable with string value. Like:

> var scene7_front_url = 'http://example.com/test=1&wid=77';

You can use replace function of string;

> scene7_front_url.replace( /&wid=([0-9]+)*/g, '&wid=100' );

The output will be;

> http://example.com/test=1&wid=100

I think that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
scene7_front_url = scene7_front_url.replace(/\&wid\=([0-9]+)*/g, '\&wid\=100')
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace` is a standard "regex" pattern matcher. Pretty much all languages come with a regex feature, so converting it from one language to another usually isn't too hard. (there are some differences between how some languages do a few things in regex, but in general it's pretty similar across the board.

PHP's syntax looks like this:

```
$output = preg_replace('/pattern/', $replaceWith, $input);
```

Javascript's syntax looks like this:

```
output = input.replace(/pattern/, replaceWith);
```

Given those rules, it should be fairly simple to convert one to the other.

But just for the sake of completeness, here's the finished code:

```
scene7_front_url = scene7_front_url.replace(/&wid=([0-9]+)*/, '&wid=100');
```

... with copy+paste of your variable names and patterns.

Hope that helps.